# Detect beacons near me in by react-native coding

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have to track the beacons near android device, i have tried to use "react-native-beacons-android", "react-native-kontaktio"  library but it's showing error. like this -->
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
**Note**: **/Users/../Desktop/.../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/codegen/generator/SchemaJsonParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 2 but an SDK XML file of version 3 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>**

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/Users/../node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/android/build.gradle' line: 30
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-beacons-manager'.

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

I attempted to link React Native using the command `react-native link`, but encountered an error stating that the command 'link' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Additionally, when trying to use the `@hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager` library and importing beacons from it, I encountered an error. I explored possible solutions, including references like [https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/blob/master/examples/samples/ranging.android.md] and [https://github.com/sashko9807/react-native-beacons-manager/commit/32d013ebff87733cccf60f62532cf509f540daf0].

I'm seeking assistance on how to resolve these issues and successfully integrate the `@hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager` library into my React Native project. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering multiple issues with integrating the react-native-beacons-android and @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager libraries. Let's break down the problems and try to address them step by step:

1.Deprecated API Warning:
The warning about a deprecated API in SchemaJsonParser.java can often be addressed by updating your dependencies. Ensure that you have the latest versions of the libraries and plugins you are using.

2.SDK XML Version Warning:
The warning about SDK XML version mismatches might be due to inconsistencies between Android Studio and command-line tools. Ensure that you are using compatible versions. You can check and update your Android Studio and SDK tools.

3.Gradle Error in react-native-beacons-manager:
The error regarding compile() in the build.gradle file suggests a possible compatibility issue with the Gradle version. Update the Gradle plugin version in your project's build.gradle file and make sure it matches the version required by the library.

4.React Native Link Issue:
If react-native link is not recognized, it might be due to a version mismatch or configuration issue. Ensure that your React Native project is set up correctly and that you are running the command from the root of your project.

5.Importing @hkpuits/react-native-beacons-manager:
If you encounter errors when importing the library, double-check the import statement and make sure it aligns with the library's documentation. It's crucial to follow the correct syntax.